# JavaScript function to update Firebase Data overwriting current data, even with my loop to check null/empty values

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm implementing an update function so that my user can update their caption values. However, if one of the spaces is left blank, the data is overwritten to an empty string in the database. I simply want to only overwrite the desired data, and leave data alone if the length of the input is null or 0.

JavaScript Function:

```
/*-----------------------------------UPDATE DATABASE DATA--------------------------------------------------------------*/

function getUpdateId(element){

    var postId = $(element).closest('div').attr('id');
    console.log(postId);
    var submit = document.getElementById("uploadButtonUpdate");

    submit.onclick = function(){

        var postData = {

            title: $('#imageTitleUpdate').val(),
            medium: $('#imageMediumUpdate').val(),
            dimensions: $('#imageDimensionsUpdate').val(),
            year: $('#imageYearUpdate').val(),
            additional: $('#additionalInfoUpdate').val()
        };


        //Check if a json element is null
        for (data in postData){
            if(postData[data] != null){
            firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/' + postId).update(postData);
            }
        }
            location.reload();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do in your `onClick` function is this:

1. You obtain data from your UI user and create a `postData` object from it
2. You iterate over the properties of the object to check if any of it has a null/missing value (null or undefined)
3. And this is where you are having the problem -  the firebase method that you are calling initiates a network request, and nobody, even javascript, doesn't know when that request will bring back a response/finish executing, and so it sends that firebase function to another thread so that running the firebase function will not block the single-threaded javascript runtime.. but then, you are running this in a `for...in` loop which is very fast. So what happens?

The conditional in the loop checks if the first property in`postData` is null (according to your code) and if it isn't, it initiates the firebase function to send data to the database in another thread (Thread 1) since it is a promise; and then immediately checks if the next property in `postData` is null, and if it isn't, it initiates the firebase function to send data to the database in another thread (Thread 2) and so on..
By the time the `for...in` loop is finished, we still have firebase functions running in other threads, updating that database path for every property value that isn't null. That's why there's an issue with what you see in your database.

Now, what I did was to remove that firebase call and make it run only once. The `for...in` loop will check for data with falsy values and tell the user that something is missing, but if nothing is missing, it will update the whole database path with the relevant data only once

```
//Check if a json element is null
let aPropertyValueIsFalsy = false;
for (prop in postData) {
  if (!!postData[prop]) {
    aPropertyValueIsFalsy = true;
    return;
  }
}
if (aPropertyValueIsFalsy == true) {
  // write code to tell user that something is missing
} else {
// send data to database
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child("Posts/" + postId)
    .update(postData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudo_Kaizen is right that you are calling update() function for each iteration of your for-loop when the current property (postData[data]) is not null. That is your first problem.

The second and more essential problem, which is also done wrong by Sudo_Kaizen, is that the update function will update all the properies of the object you are handing in to it and that off course only happens if all properties are set.

to save the fields with a none trivial value (e.g. null or 0) change your code like this:

```js
function getUpdateId(element){

  var postId = $(element).closest('div').attr('id');
  console.log(postId);
  var submit = document.getElementById("uploadButtonUpdate");

  submit.onclick = function(){

    var postData = [
      {title: $('#imageTitleUpdate').val()},
      {medium: $('#imageMediumUpdate').val()},
      {dimensions: $('#imageDimensionsUpdate').val()},
      {year: $('#imageYearUpdate').val()},
      {additional: $('#additionalInfoUpdate').val()}
    ];
    
    // Check if a json element is null
    for (const data of postData){
      for (const prop in data) {
        if(data[prop] !== null && data[prop] !== 0){
          firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/' + postId ).update(data);
        }
      }
    }
    location.reload();
  };
}
```

Also check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

Comment: Unfortunately this adds in a 'data: " " ' field within my database now, no matter which specific data I chose to update

Comment: So to clarify, my fields in in the Json are: {Title: " ", Medium: " ", Year: " ", Dimensions: " ";} but when try and update, say the 'Title', the actual json value of 'Title' will remain unchanged, but instead the edited value will be stored as {data: "what I typed"} within the data. Thus it appends a new field versus edits what I'm trying to change

Comment: @sazar97 sorry, my bad. the problem is, that the property name cant be set dynamically. I refactored the answer und used an array instead of a dictionary. Hope this one works for you...

Comment: Unfortunately everything is still getting overwrited. I've tried a few more methods as well as yours and the data will still always get overwrited to blank if I choose to leave those fields empty. Really frustrating but I thank you for your responses thus far!

Comment: @sazar97 That's weired... Can you  use a debugger and check if the expression inside the if clause is executed when it shouldn't!?